# Where is the Maven that Eclipse/STS is using so I can run it from command line?

Tags: eclipse, macos, maven

I have a Java Spring MVC web app in Eclipse/STS.

I can build the WAR file by right-clicking on the project and choose "Run As > Maven Install".  The WAR file is created under \target\MYPROJECT.WAR

Now I want to run this from the command line because I'm writing a script that will build the WAR, and make a deliverable ZIP file (with the WAR, readmes, docs, and config files).

I'm on a Mac, when I run 'mvn install' from the root of my project, it says "command not found: mvn".  I prefer not to setup a separate maven installation, I'd rather use the same one that Eclipse is using.

Where is the Maven installation that Eclipse/STS is using?

Comment: Eclipse does not use the command line interface to Maven, it makes direct calls to the APIs in the various maven jars (which are in the org.eclipse.m2e.maven.xxxx plug-ins).

Comment: Ok ... so if I understand correctly, I have to install my own maven in order use it from the cmd line.  Correct?

Comment: Yes, you need a separate install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question after getting helpful comment from @greg-449

The answer is, you cannot (or are not supposed to) use Eclipse/STS's built-in Maven from the command line.

So instead I installed a separate Maven instance.